# Recording keyboard input to pseudoterminal

Tags: python, c, unix, tty, pty

I'm trying to record the keyboard input to a pseudoterminal in python using the `pty` module in python's standard library. I'm having some difficulty capturing only the keyboard input. While I can easily record the stdout using the callback listed [here (in the module documentation)](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pty.html#pty.spawn), I can't figure out how to get the keyboard input. Should I be using something like `termios` in conjunction with `pty`?

If this is possible in another language like C, please also tell!

Comment: If you want to make a keylogger, use `pyhook` or `pygame.keyboardevent()` as capturing keyboard events. I did a keylogger before with pygame actually,  [Well](http://img.memecdn.com/if-it-looks-stupid-but-works-it-ain-amp-039-t-stupid_o_2965717.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try that. Note that I don't want to record input to the whole computer, just the tty I'm emulating.